# Understanding the implementation of label/5 in clpfd

Tags: prolog, implementation, swi-prolog, clpfd, labeling

I am trying to understand the **implementation** (I understand the usage) of the label/5 predicate in the `clpfd` library:

([copied from here](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/clp/clpfd.pl?show=src#label/5))

```
1824label([], _, _, _, Consistency) :- !,
1825        (   Consistency = upto_in(I0,I) -> I0 = I
1826        ;   true
1827        ).
1828label(Vars, Selection, Order, Choice, Consistency) :-
1829        (   Vars = [V|Vs], nonvar(V) -> label(Vs, Selection, Order, Choice, Consistency)
1830        ;   select_var(Selection, Vars, Var, RVars),
1831            (   var(Var) ->
1832                (   Consistency = upto_in(I0,I), fd_get(Var, _, Ps), all_dead(Ps) ->
1833                    fd_size(Var, Size),
1834                    I1 is I0*Size,
1835                    label(RVars, Selection, Order, Choice, upto_in(I1,I))
1836                ;   Consistency = upto_in, fd_get(Var, _, Ps), all_dead(Ps) ->
1837                    label(RVars, Selection, Order, Choice, Consistency)
1838                ;   choice_order_variable(Choice, Order, Var, RVars, Vars, Selection, Consistency)
1839                )
1840            ;   label(RVars, Selection, Order, Choice, Consistency)
1841            )
1842        ).
```

especially the marked part (obviously the important part) confuses me:

- I am not quite sure what `fd_get` (`/3` or `/5`) does
- `all_dead` using some kind of `propagator` (which I haven't looked into yet tbh)
- How does this "enumerate" `Var`?

I am obviously missing some integral parts to the proving mechanism that probably need to be understood for this, so i am curious about some higher level explanation (with maybe a couple of resources to read on) about the behavior of this implementation.

Comment: Of interest: [labeling/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=labeling/2), [label/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=label/1)

Comment: FYI, [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1613573/mat) who wrote the code no longer hangs out on SO so this may not be the best place to ask.

Comment: I like the question and while I am comfortable using `label` I too don't fully understand its use, e.g. sometimes I can get a solution without using label and sometimes I need label.  I think your question would help out the community better if you gave an example in your question where `label/1` or `labeling/2`l is required for ground answers and explain what you know about it. Often when I answer a question like this the first response I get is like, `I tried that` or `I noticed that` but the OP did not note that in the question and I find that I just wasted my time.

Comment: There are three options: `upto_ground` (default), `upto_in` and `upto_in(-Size)`. Note that the original author [stopped development for SWI](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/issues/108#issuecomment-301327407). The current implementation `clpz` runs on  SICStus and Scryer.

Comment: Of  interest:  Scryer Prolog [discussions](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog/discussions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: The following answer is only my educated guess after browsing through the code and playing a bit with it in SWISH.

First of all, it appears that the entire marked part and the two lines below it  (i.e. lines 1836-1837) relate to an undocumented option to `labeling/2`, which I'll call `upto_in` (after the name of the functor). I'll try to explain what I believe this option does.

Normally, when `labeling/2` is called, all the FD variables (in its second argument) are ground upon success. This is really what labeling does: assign variables one after the other until they are all assigned. For instance, in the following snippet, `labeling/2` succeeds 6 times with both `X` and `Y` ground:

```
?- [X,Y] ins 1..4, X #< Y, labeling([],[X,Y]).
X = 1, Y = 2 ;
X = 1, Y = 3 ;
X = 1, Y = 4 ;
X = 2, Y = 3 ;
X = 2, Y = 4 ;
X = 3, Y = 4
```

As a comparison, when `labeling/2` is not used, then we can see the (reduced) domain of the two variables and the fact that a constraint is still pending.

```
?- [X,Y] ins 1..4, X #< Y.
X in 1..3, X #=< Y + -1, Y in 2..4
```

When a constraint is pending, it means that each combination of values for the variables (in this case `X` and `Y`) might or might not be a solution. Conversely, if no constraint is pending, then we know that every combination of values is a solution.  In some applications, then one might then consider stopping labeling when we know for sure that all value combinations are solutions. And in a nutshell, this is what the option `upto_in` does: It tells to avoid labeling when no constraint is left pending. Back to our running example, this shows as:

```
?- [X,Y] ins 1..4, X #< Y, labeling([upto_in],[X,Y]).
X = 1, Y in 2..4 ;
X = 2, Y in 3..4 ;
X = 3, Y = 4
```

So the first solution means that for `X = 1`, `Y` can take all values from 2 to 4.

Note that `upto_in` comes in two flavors, with the first one shown above, and the second one taking an argument, which represents the number of ground solutions contained in the produced answer. So:

```
?- [X,Y] ins 1..4, X #< Y, labeling([upto_in(K)],[X,Y]).
X = 1, Y in 2..4, K = 3 ;
X = 2, Y in 3..4, K = 2 ;
X = 3, Y = 4, K = 1
```

As another example, if one removes the only constraint, we see that the number of (ground) solution is the Cartesian product of the domains (and no actual labeling takes place).

```
?- [X,Y] ins 1..4, labeling([upto_in(K)],[X,Y]).
K = 16, X in 1..4, Y in 1..4
```

This second option may be useful for instance when one wants to count the number of solutions to a problem. Then `upto_in/1` allows one to shortcut labeling of "irrelevant" variables for better performance, while keeping track of the count of actual solutions.

Now, to answer more specific questions:

- `fd_get(V,D,Ps)` "returns" for a variable `V`: its current domain `D` and a structure `Ps` with (3 lists of) propagators associated to it. A propagator is basically the internal implementation of a posted constraint, whose role is to remove impossible values from domains. In the examples above, `Ps` would contain (a representation of?) the propagator for the inequality constraint, and that propagator would have removed in all cases `1` from the domain of `Y` and `4` from the domain of `X`. `fd_get/5` returns in addition the upper and lower bounds of the domain.
- `all_dead/1` seems to check whether all the propagators associated to a variable are "dead", meaning in this cases that all combinations of values in the domain of the variables appearing in them are solutions. (I say "seem" because this bit really touches to the internals of the `clpfd` library and I don't want to dig too far.)
- It does not really enumerate `Var`. To explain what the marked code does in a sentence, I would write: "If the `upto_in` option is used and there is no constraint that might reduce the domain of `Var` any further, then skip enumerating `Var` (and multiply some accumulator by the size of its domain)."

Hope this helps your understanding. And if someone more knowledgeable finds mistakes or holes in my explanation, feel free to fix them.

Comment: Yes someone other than the OP gave an up-vote.